# How To Create a Picture Library in SharePoint Online(office 365) Using CSOM-JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app, csom

Currently I have created SharePoint Hosted App (*Picture Slider*) using Napa Office 365 Development tool. So far, I have created picture Library Manually, 
and **now trying to create Picture Library using CSOM**  JavaScript  in office 365

How to achieve this task?

Comment: Do you wanna create this library in Appweb?

Comment: trying to create in Hostweb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code to create the picture Library using Javscript:

```
function CreatePictureLibrary() {
  var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

  // *********** Host Web Change
  var hostUrl = GetUrlKeyValue("SPHostUrl");
  var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
  var web = hostContext.get_web();
  // *********** Host Web Change

  var list=web.get_lists();
  var picLibCreation = new SP.ListCreationInformation(); 
  picLibCreation.set_title("MyDocumentLibrary"); //list title
  picLibCreation.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.PictureLibrary); //Picture library type
  list.add(picLibCreation)
  context.load(list);
  context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    alert(picLibCreation.title + "Created");
  }, function(){
    alert('Failed to Create the Document Library. Error:' + args.get_message());
  });
}
```

If you want to create the library in Host web, change the way you generate `context` , rest code remains same.

Comment: ok ,i'm Working on It

Comment: I updated the code sample to add the list to the host web

Comment: @RobWindsor Perfect !