# How to Upload Images to SharePoint Online(Office 365) Picture-library using CSOM (Java Script)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom

currently created [Picture Library using csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148535/how-to-create-a-picture-library-in-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-using-csom-java)

on host Web in my last question, now trying to add some Images to that Library, So for that created Image folder into SharePoint Hosted App.
how to achive above task

Comment: Just a heads up: the API you're looking to use is (or was at one point) called JSOM. (JavaScript SharePoint Object Model) CSOM (Client SharePoint Object Model) is currently only implemented for .NET languages. Both are based on the SharePoint Client Query Protocol, but since each implementation comes with its own limitations, you might find more relevant information using the proper term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload images using **File.SaveBinaryDirect Method** in sharepoint.

Go through [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect(v=office.14)), Also work in SharePoint Online.

Example

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
 using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
 {
     var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
     var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
     var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);

     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, fs, true);
 }
}
```

**Note**: NetworkCredential is used in on-premises environment, SharePointOnlineCredentials in SharePoint Online

Comment: If you get answer please mark as Answer..!!

Comment: m trying to use JavaScrip (CSOM)                                                                 If  not Possible Using Java Scrip then  give some suggesions

Comment: Okey.. Let me know if not done through javascript..

Comment: after some research found that not possible to upload images in library using java script ,                              can i use REST API for that?

Comment: Unless it's changed since the last time I checked, `SaveBinaryDirect` uses SharePoint's [WebDAV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa486282%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) endpoint to upload files. To use it yourself, you'd need to direct a `PUT` HTTP request with the request body containing your uploaded image. Not sure that really helps in your case, but if you'd like me to post an answer with more info, let me know.